# Find the longest element (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, height, addclass

I use this script to equalize heights of elements:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.autoheight = function () {
        var height = 0,
            reset = $.browser.msie ? "1%" : "auto";
        return this.css("height", reset).each(function () {
            height = Math.max(height, this.offsetHeight);
        }).css("height", height).each(function () {
            var h = this.offsetHeight;
            if (h > height) {
                $(this).css("height", height - (h - height));
            };
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

I'd like to add just one extra functionality to it - addclass 'longest' to the longest element found when equalizing heights, what do I change in the above script?

Many thanks.

Comment: Its about equalizing heights, so 'longest' is more appropriate?

Comment: "Tallest" or "highest" or possibly "largest" is more appropriate. Width -> widest, Height -> tallest/highest, length -> longest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this more pseudo-code than anything as it hasn't been tested (or even run). Changed code inside //new code comment

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.autoheight = function () {
        var height = 0,
            highest = 0, //new code
            reset = $.browser.msie ? "1%" : "auto";
        return this.css("height", reset).each(function () {
            height = Math.max(height, this.offsetHeight);
            //new code
            if (height > highest) {
              highest = height;
              $("*").removeClass("longest");
              $(this).addClass("longest"); 
            };
            //new code
        }).css("height", height).each(function () {
            var h = this.offsetHeight;
            if (h > height) {
                $(this).css("height", height - (h - height));
            };
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Just checked Alex's jsFiddle example and it seems to work OK. You can inspect the result DOM using Firebug and see that one div has the 'longest' class added to it.

Answer (score 2):

Steve Claridge's above solution you say doesn't work - works fine for me; http://jsfiddle.net/ZqFp5/ (tested in chrome only)

Though using the

```
 $("*")
```

selector is somewhat inefficient in a large DOM, consider adding a class to the div's to use a more specific selector if possible.

```
 $(".foo")
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember stumbling across this site. Does this help?
http://www.queness.com/post/126/useful-and-handy-jquery-tips-and-tricks

Read number 10. Columns of equal height.

Comment: No, the one I'm using is perfect, I just need to addclass to the tallest element.